# create a webservice using rest to communicate with a jSON - tutorial

Tags: ios, json, web-services, rest

i'm looking at a tutorial which let me learn and make a webservice in REST using PHP to communicate a JSON to my iOS application.

I don't find any "good" tutorial or a tutorial which make me learn and create something which look like a bit like i want.

could you please help me and put me in the good direction ^^

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

### Client

For the client side I would suggest you use [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) which is a very convenient framework for consuming REST-based webservers. It works for XML And JSON. I have used it before and can definitely recommend it. There are also various examples, which shows you how to use the framework.

### Server

Depending on what you want you might do one of the following options:

1. Easy: If you want to focus more on the client you can simply put your `.json` files in a folder in your Public folder of your dropbox and consume those data files. You can then make changes to them with the Text Editor of your choice
2. If you want to have more control and have a Database etc. I suggest using [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org), which is like Rails for PHP. You have a bit of a learning curve there but the framework is quite powerful and there are lots of resources out there. Like [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) it follows the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) Paradigm.

**Update:**

I just stumbled upon a [nice step-by-step tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/) for the iPhone which loads json-based twitter-data and displays it in a `UITableView`

[image: twitter client]

Comment: btw, should i start lika that :

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question / remark. If you're wondering whether to use 1. oder 2. then this might depend on how comfortable you feel with PHP already. However, it tends to be a good thing to start basic and then continue adding more stuff. Otherwise you might have to many possible factors that might fail which makes trouble-shooting more difficult.